# JSON decode multiple nested JSON in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, json, wordpress, decode

I am using a page builder called King composer for wordpress, where i am trying to build some custom functions, like is intended.

My problem is, that the build-in background color picker is base64 encoding the background properties, So i need to decode it - But first i need to decode the 'my-css' json, so that i can access the different properties.

this is the return of what i get from the builder.

```
array (
    '_id' => '69391',
    'image' => '294,9,16',
    'gallery-text' => 'Dette er nærmest et galleri',
    'my-css' => '{
           `kc-css`:{
                  `any`:{
                       `typography`{`color|`:`#ffffff`},
                       `background`{`background|`:`longBase64StringHere`},
                       `box`:{`margin|`:`100px inherit inherit inherit`}
                       }
                    }
                 }',
      )
```

So far i have tried:

```
 $decodedBackground = base64_decode($atts['my-css']);
```

which returns as null

then i tried :

```
 $decodedJson = json_decode($atts['my-css']);
```

which returns : null

Also tried some other stuff that went horriably wrong

I don't really understand it, I can access the other properties fine, since it is just a part of an array, but the CSS part, I cannot comprehend. I think I need to go deeper in - but I can't get it to work.

Been stuck for about 1.5 hours now, so any help or pointers would be appreciated

/*------ EDIT -----*/

So this is how i am trying to inspect the decoded json afterwards - 
might be important.

```
 $decodedJson = json_decode($atts['my-css'], true);
 echo '<pre>' . var_export($decodedJson, true) . '</pre>';
```

Comment: that will also return null - tried it earlier while writing my question.

Comment: Sorry the content under my-css is not a valid json.. please make sure

Comment: The value of `$atts['my-css']` doesn't use a standard encoding. It is not JSON and I cannot see anything encoded using base64 in the data you posted.

Comment: Is there a way of changing the encoding, or another way of accessing the singlular values in my-css?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is maybe not the best way to do because the JSON in `kc-css` is not well formated, but this code works for your case:

```php
// Refomating JSON
$atts['my-css'] = str_replace('`{', '`:{', $atts['my-css']);
$atts['my-css'] = str_replace('`', '"', $atts['my-css']);

$json = json_decode($atts['my-css'], true);
```

Comment: This works for this time - but having to do this for everytime I need a css value will be a bother. Thank you - I managed to get to the string be going 
     echo '<pre>' . var_export($json['kc-css']['any']['background']['background|'], true) . '</pre>';